# Error with Property Validation in Form Submission in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, modelstate

I have a simple form on an ASP.NET MVC site that I'm building. This form is submitted, and then I validate that the form fields aren't null, empty, or improperly formatted.

However, when I use `ModelState.AddModelError()` to indicate validation errors from my controller code, I **get an error when my view is re-rendered**. In Visual Studio, I get that the following line is highlighted as being the location of the error:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("Email")%>
```

The error is the following:

> **NullReferenceException** was unhandled by user code - object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My complete code for that textbox is the following:

```
<p>
<label for="Email">Your Email:</label>
<%=Html.TextBox("Email")%>
<%=Html.ValidationMessage("Email", "*") %>
</p>
```

Here's how I'm doing that validation in my controller:

```
        try
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailAddress address = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
        }
        catch
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Should not be empty or invalid");
        }

return View();
```

Note: this **applies to all of my fields**, not just my Email field, **as long as they are invalid**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a horrible bug/feature (call in whatever) in ASP.NET MVC the helper that you may fix by calling [SetModelValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.setmodelvalue(VS.90).aspx) like this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Should not be empty or invalid");
ModelState.SetModelValue("Email", new ValueProviderResult("raw value", "attempted value", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

By the way is there any reason you would write all this code when you could simply annotate your view model:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    [RegularExpression("Some bulletproof regex you could google to validate email address", ErrorMessage = "Should not be empty or invalid")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and leave the data binder do the heavy lifting.

Comment: So, for the first code example: you have to have both lines, right? In other words, I first call AddModelError and then I call SetModelValue? Also, what are raw-value and attempted-value? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you need both lines. RawValue points to an object which has the the property used for updating. AttemptedValue stores what the user actually entered. I believe you may leave them blank.

Comment: Could you give an example of a RawValue, such as an email property? I'm sort of confused.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce.

Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string email)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Should not be empty or invalid");
    }
    return View();
}
```

View

```
    <%using (Html.BeginForm() { %>
    <p>
        <label for="Email">
            Your Email:</label>
        <%=Html.TextBox("Email")%>
        <%=Html.ValidationMessage("Email", "*") %>
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
    <%} %>
```